# Setting CBUS Bit Bang Mode in FT231x to use parallel pins as GPIO

Tags: python, gpio, ftdi

I am using the FTDI chip [FT231x](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT231X.html) for serial UART communication from my linux laptop to a micro-controller.

Besides that I want to use [CBUS Bit Bang Mode](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Knowledgebase/index.html?cbusbitbangmode.htm) to use the pin as GPIO pin.

I have tried the [pylibftdi python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylibftdi), but I am unable to get the listed devices. Even if I set the rules in udev and run with sudo too.

Can anyone help me how to interface the FT231x pin in *CBUS Bit Bang Mode*?
Or does there exist a library which I can use if that'd be easier?

Answer (score 0):

For cbus to work you need to set the ftdi to d2xx mode from the virtual mode.
I used the software to convert it to d2xx mode as cbus only works in d2xx mode.

As python pylibftdi was not working I used ftd2xx library from the offical FTDI site  to make it work.
http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm
Here is the link to download the library based on your processor.